# Nokogiri Scraping

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'd like to scrap the title of each video and the links.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.stream2u.me/'))
doc.css('.lshpanel').each do |link|
  binding.pry
  puts link.elements[1].text
  puts "LINKS ARE: "
  ## Cant figure out how to get to the links...
end
```

Can someone please help! Been working on it for like an hour and cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the links with the `css` method and then iterate over the collection to pull the `href` attributes.  For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.stream2u.me/'))

doc.css('.lshpanel').each do |d| 
  puts d.css('.lshevent').text
  d.css('a').each { |el| puts el['href'] }
end
```